# Ordering Pages and Increasing Navigation

Tags: pages, navigation

Is there a way of ordering my pages on my WordPress site so they appear in the navigation bar of the order i choose?
ALSO:
When i have too many wordpress pages for the navigation, it hides some pages. Is there a way to stop this so all pages are shown?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to create a [custom menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen#Create_a_Menu). That would give you control over the order that the pages appear in.